# having trouble passing a value to a function parameter javascript

Tags: javascript, object, parameters

Here is my code:

Constructor function:

```
 function Box (//parameters) {  
  // code for constructor function  
  }
```

Here is where I get values to create new objects:

```
  function getBoxValues() {
   //code to get values

if (name == null || name == "") {                    
     alert("Please enter a name for your box");
     return;
   }
   else {
    var newbox = new Box("id", name, color, number, "coordinates");  //creates "newbox"
    boxes.push(newbox);                                       
    addBox(newbox); 
    counter++;                                          
   }
```

Here is where I add the boxes to the page:

```
function addBox(newbox) {  
   for (var i = 0; i < newbox.number; i++) {                                 
   var scene = document.getElementById("scene");              
   var div = document.createElement("div"); 
   div.className += " " + "box"; 
   div.innerHTML += newbox.name; 
   div.style.backgroundColor = newbox.color; 
   var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * (scene.offsetWidth-101));
   var y = Math.floor(Math.random() * (scene.offsetHeight-101));
   div.style.left = x + "px";
   div.style.top = y + "px";                     
   scene.appendChild(div);                           
    } 
   return div;                        
  }

  display();

  function display(div) {
  div.innerHTML += "alert";
  console.log("alert");
  }
```

My issue is that I'm trying to pass the value of div into the display function so that I can write in the innerHTML of the object. I keep getting a message in my console that says that div is undefined. I think that this is probably an issue with scope, but I'm having trouble figuring it out.

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `display()` with no arguments, of course it's undefined ;)

Pass the appropriate argument to the function call, and it'll all work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
display(); // <-- you call it with no argument

function display(div) {  // <-- there is 'div'
div.innerHTML += "alert"; // <-- undefined error
console.log("alert");
}
```

Comment: thanks, but the thing is is that I had to move display(div); into the addBox(newbox) function. and it only displays "alert" in one of the boxes.